# Merging configuration values in Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a Maven submodule which needs to append a string to the existing value of a configuration option. The parent module looks like this:

```
<!-- in parent -->
<plugin>
   ...
   <configuration>
       <someOption>A</someOption>
   </configuration>
   ...
</plugin>
```

The submodule needs to append a string to `someOption`, such that the effect is as if the submodule has done

```
<!-- in child -->
<plugin>
   ...
   <configuration>
       <someOption>A B</someOption>
   </configuration>
   ...
</plugin>
```

I've looked at the `combine.*` attributes, but none of them seems to do what I want. Is there a way to do this? Would it be possible to access the parent's value of `someOption` from the child?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you will have to fall back to a property.

```
<!-- in parent -->
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <foo-plugin.config.someOption>A<foo-plugin.config.someOption>
  </properties>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <someOption>${foo-plugin.config.someOption}</someOption>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
      ...
    <plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

and then the child redefines the property based on the parent

```
<!-- in child -->
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <foo-plugin.config.someOption>${foo-plugin.config.someOption} B<foo-plugin.config.someOption>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

Not ideal, but the only solution I can see right now